# How can I check if row exists in multiple tables with one query?

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, where-clause

I have three tables where I want to see if a row exists in any one of them.

Here are my three queries. How can I combine them into one?

```
$dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM employees WHERE email = :email");
$dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM teachers WHERE email = :email");

if(!$row) { // If row not found
    // continue with registration
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` query. This will return multiple rows if the user has different `id` values in multiple tables but since you only need to know if one or more rows exist that is fine.

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email
UNION
SELECT id FROM employees WHERE email = :email
UNION
SELECT id FROM teachers WHERE email = :email
```

Alternatively you could use an `EXISTS` expression to get a simple yes/no result from the query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email = :email)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE email = :email)
```

If you're interested in knowing which table the email address is in, you can modify the `UNION` query to return that information as well:

```
SELECT 'users' AS `table`, id FROM users WHERE email = :email
UNION
SELECT 'employees', id FROM employees WHERE email = :email
UNION
SELECT 'teachers', id FROM teachers WHERE email = :email
```

Comment: Consider if the id is useful or if you want to identify which table. e.g. `SELECT 'users' AS 'which_table',id FROM USER ... UNION SELECT 'employees',id ....`

Comment: @danblack OPs question seems to imply they don't really care "I want to see if a row exists in any one of them" and also `if(!$row) { // If row not found`. But worth adding anyway... have edited. thanks

Comment: Which one would be faster performance wise? The `UNION` or `EXISTS`?

Comment: @TimmyBalk  probably the `EXISTS` as it can stop processing as soon as it gets a result e.g. if there is a matching value in `users` then there is no need to do the other two `SELECTS` as the result will be true regardless of whether the email address is in the other two tables.